# Multiple types of Distributed Cache in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, caching, asp.net-core, session-state

Suppose I have a ASP.NET Core 2.x application.

I would like to use Redis for standard `IDistributedCache` dependency injection, but use SQL Server Distributed cache as the backing for Session middleware.

Is this possible?  If so, how would you go about configuring this in `Startup.cs`?

Answer (score 1):

The distributed session state storage injects the `IDistributedCache` instance by default. This means you should configure the SQL Server distributed cache as the default one if you would like to use that for session state.

For your own caching purposes, you could create a "wrapper interface" which specifically represents the Redis cache (such as `IRedisCache`), register it and inject that in your middleware/controllers/services. For example:

```
public interface IRedisDistributedCache : IDistributedCache
{
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add Redis caching
    services.AddDistributedRedisCache();
    services.AddSingleton<IRedisDistributedCache, RedisCache>();

    // Add SQL Server caching as the default cache mechanism
    services.AddDistributedSqlServerCache();
}

public class FooController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRedisDistributedCache _redisCache;

    public FooController(IRedisDistributedCache redisCache)
    {
        _redisCache = redisCache;
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you initialize the Redis instance in this case?  Normally, I've initialized it  in services.AddDistributedRedisCache() call.

Comment: @user1142433 see the code example. I'm calling `AddDistributedRedisCache()` just like you normally would, and afer that bind `RedisCache` implemenation to the `IRedisDistributedCache` "wrapper interface".

Comment: So you're adding two IDistributedCache cache items to the DI service (one Redis and one SQL based)?    And when Session calls for an IDistributedCache implementation it gets the SQL version because you added it to the service config after the Redis version?   In other words, how does the service resolver decide which IDistributedCache it gives to the Service middleware?

Comment: @user1142433 that's correct. The container will pick the last one you registered.

Comment: I see now how it should work in principle.  Unfortunately, the sample won't compile because "There is no implicit conversion from RedisCache to IRedisDistributedCache" on line  services.AddSingleton<IRedisDistributedCache, RedisCache> ();

Comment: @user1142433 sorry, I overlooked that. You could instead register `RedisCache` as both service and implementation (e.g. `AddSingleton<RedisCache>()` and inject a `RedisCache` instance. Please let me know if it works.